# Is there a way to resize my JFrame without drawing excess shapes?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, drawing

I'm writing a program that draws randomized shapes within a window at an interval. I want the shapes to be stored in an array, as I will be needing to retrieve the information about each one from a text file later on. It works fine as long as I don't try and resize my window. Whenever I stretch it out, a whole lot of new shapes appear (quicker than intended), possibly beacuse repaint() gets called each time I resize, but I can't figure out how to prevent it from doing that. In other words, how do I prevent surplus objects from appearing on resizing?

I'd appreciate any tips, not only those directly related to my question, but any of the programming choices I've made. I'm a beginner.

I hope I made it clear. I will be happy to provide more details if you need any.

```
public Window() {
        setTitle("shapes");
        setSize(800, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        setVisible(true);
    }

 public void paint(Graphics g) {
        addShape();
        g.clearRect(1,1, getWidth(), getHeight());
        for (Figure figure : myFigures) {
            figure.draw(g);
            System.out.println(figure.toString());
        }
    }

  public Thread drawThread() {
        return new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

private void addShape() {
        int whichFigure = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
        switch (whichFigure) {
            case 1:
                myFigures.add(new Oval((int) (Math.random() * getWidth()), (int) (Math.random() * getHeight()), (int) (Math.random() * 100), (int) (Math.random() * 100)));
                System.out.println("oval added");
                break;
            case 2:
                myFigures.add(new Rectangle((int) (Math.random() * getWidth()), (int) (Math.random() * getHeight()), (int) (Math.random() * 100), (int) (Math.random() * 100)));
                System.out.println("rect added");
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not call `addShape` from a paint method.  As you are discovering, you have no control over when painting methods are called.  Resizing isn’t the only thing that can trigger painting.  Moving or raising the window can.  Even moving the mouse over the window can.  Never change your data in a painting method.

Change your data in another place, such as right before calling repaint().  All Swing operations need to take place in the AWT event dispatch thread, and data used by Swing operations also needs to be modified in that thread (unless you take steps to make the code thread-safe, such as synchronization).  The easiest way to regularly execute code in that thread is by using the [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html) class:

```
public Timer drawThread() {
    return new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            addShape();
            repaint();
        }
    });
}
```

Note that, similar to a Thread, a Timer needs to have its [start()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html#start%28%29) (or [restart()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html#restart%28%29)) method called.

Comment: (1+) Also, Don't override paint() on the frame. Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent()` of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.